# Is there department that issues trefunds for?

Tags: etherscan

is it possible to be refunded ETH by etherscan or refunded tokens both that where sent on accident

Comment: Hi there. As per the answer to your other question, if you've sent your ETH to an address that you don't own, and you don't know who that address belongs to, then you won't be able to get your ETH back, I'm afraid. Etherscan is just a chain explorer: they let you view the addresses/accounts and other data stored in the blockchain. They don't have any control over the addresses.

Comment: I know it's of little use now, but always send a test transaction using a small amount of ETH first, if possible. Wait until it's confirmed and check it's gone to where you were expecting it to go.